# Axios post call in paystack callback method not firing

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to integrate the paystack payment gateway into my vuejs/laravel application, using the vue-paystack plugin, test mode for now. After successful payment, i need to store the response and some other variables in my table. In my template, i called the paystack component like so;

```
<paystack
    :amount="amount"
    :email="email"
    :paystackkey="paystackkey"
    :reference="reference"
    :callback="saveResponse"
    :close="close"
    :embed="false"
>
   <i class="fas fa-money-bill-alt"></i>
   Make Payment
</paystack>
```

In my callback method, i am attempting to store some of the response object values in my own table;

```
saveResponse(resp){
    axios.post(this.api + `/store_response`, {
       resp: resp
    }).then((res)=>{
       console.log(res.data)
    })
}
```

However, this method isn't firing even after successful payment. If i console.log the response in the `saveResponse` method, i get the response, but the axios call isn't just firing. Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: You should get in touch with Paystack support about this https://support.paystack.com

Comment: I assume you already imported axios, can you share value of `this.api` ?

Comment: Also put catch when api failed. And console there